# Is this vertical gap in the concrete block foundation something to worry about?

Tags: repair, concrete, walls, brick, structural

I'm looking at a home that has a vertical gap or crack running the height of the exposed concrete block foundation. The crack is near the center of the home, about a foot to the right of the concrete steps leading up to the front door. It looks like the home owner has filled the crack, hopefully a suitable repair (and not just masking the issue).

Are gaps of this type common? Trying to gauge how concerned I should be about this. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: before i could comment, i'd want to see the crack from the inside.  Cracks from settling are common, so age, displacement of the crack, and other factors effect the diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see a corresponding crack in the crawlspace when I was down there. The house was built in 1950.

Comment: small cracks in block foundations are pretty common on a house that age. I always look at both sides if possible and especially look for how much the blocks have displaced. Usually not a big deal if there is little to no displacement.